# Help on calculating this double integral on a polar surface

Tags: integration, polar-coordinates

I want to calculate $I=\iint_R y^2dA$ where $R$ is the surface bounded by the curve $r=a(1+\cos\theta)$ for $\theta$ ranging between $0$ and $2\pi$.

Attempt: To calculate this as a double integral in polar coordintes we have:

$$I=\iint_R r^2\sin^2\theta=\int\limits_{0}^{2\pi}d\theta\int\limits_{0}^{a(1+\cos\theta)} r^2\sin^2\theta\cdot r\,dr\\=\int\limits_{0}^{2\pi}\sin^2\theta\,dθ\int\limits_{0}^{a(1+\cos\theta)}r^3\,dr=\int\limits_{0}^{2\pi}\sin^2\theta\frac{a^4(1+\cos\theta)^4}{4}\,d\theta$$

But I am stuck from here on. Is there a better way for solving this from scratch? Or can my attempt be completed? Any help, hint or solution would be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, if I understood you properly then we have something like this $$\int \int_R y^2 ~dA$$

where $R$ is the region bounded by $ r= a(1+\cos\theta)$ and $\theta$ goes from 0 to $2\pi$. 
$$ \int_{\theta = 0}^{2\pi} \int_{r=0}^{a(1+\cos\theta)} r^3 \sin^2 \theta dr d\theta$$

$$\int_{\theta=0}^{2\pi} \sin^2\theta \frac{a^4(1+\cos\theta)^4}{4} d\theta$$ You can integrate the above expression to get the value of $\frac{21}{32}\pi a^4$.

Now, your question about how to carry out the integral is easy to answer, just take $\frac{a^4}{4}$ out of the integral and then expand the $\sin^2\theta (1+\cos\theta)^4$. After expansion the integrals will become some of very common ones (that is they will involve only some powers of $\sin$ and $\cos$).

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks. Is there any better way other than expanding (1+cosθ)^4?

Comment: For example part by part or substitution or some other thing?

Comment: @FarhadRouhbakhsh No, substitution would make our work more tedious and I don't think we will achieve something. After all, we are substituting when we get terms after expansion. And of course, integration by parts will not help here.